# CFURLCreateWithString error from outlook on OSX Lion

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, osx-lion

After I upgraded to OSX Lion Outlook 2011 for mac has been very slow.

My system console shows thousands of this error:

> 12-02-22 10:09:10.255 AM Microsoft Outlook: CFURLCreateWithString was passed this invalid URL string: '/EWS/Exchange.asmx' (a file system path instead of an URL string). The URL created will not work with most file URL functions. CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath or CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPathRelativeToBase should be used instead.

Has anyone else seen this error, or know of a fix?